# Port forwarding in docker

Tags: docker

I have connected to a remote database from my machine via port forwarding and can access this database without a problem.

On the other hand, I have also created a docker container inside my machine with `--network host` and have tried to connect to the remote database from within the container running inside my machine.

With the exact same code i get and an error and it seems the port forwarded from the database in my pc is not also forwarded inside the docker container.

Using `-p port_n:port_n` also gives an error since it says that the port on my laptop is already in use (forwarded).

How can I make the port forwarded in my machine also accessible inside a docker container?

Comment: Show us the exact commands you gave and the full error messages.

Comment: Can you help understand why your'e using port forwarding to remote db and not connect direct?

Comment: A container normally runs in an isolated network environment.  The `docker run -p` option goes in the other direction from what you need, and host networking doesn't work on Docker Desktop or other VM-based solutions and conflicts with other core Docker networking options.  Can you use one of the setups from [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach) to reach the port on the host?

Answer (score 0):

Host networking means there is no isolation for the container. The host network interfaces are directly accessed by the container. Therefore port forwarding isn't supported since you would be forwarding from one interface to the same interface.

Ideally you would not use host networking, allowing docker to isolate the container, with the exception of forwarded ports. If you are not able to do that, and require the use of host networking, then you would access any ports the application is listening on directly.